# A group with 3 Sylow 2-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroup(the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups $G$ are $3$), and let for every prime $p$ (not equal to $2$) Sylow $p$-subgroups are normal in $G$. I am looking for an example for group $G$ that is not supersolvable. Thanks.

Comment: There are no such examples.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Thank you. Is $G$ supersolvable? If $G$ is supersolvable then, how we can prove it.

Comment: I don't feel like writing out the details. Let $K$ be the kernel of the conjugation action of $G$ on its Sylow $2$-subgroups. Then $K$ is nilpotent and $G/K \cong S_3$. The inverse image of subgroups of $G/K$ of order $2$ and $3$ are also nilpotent. That's enough to give $G$ supersolvable.